# Circuitry to eliminate spectator mode

Tags: rec-room

I was wondering if there was circuitry we could use to get someone out of spectator mode.

Spectator mode seems like a glitch where players spawn into a game but they cannot kill or be killed. So far the best fix is leaving and rejoining a game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always set up a triggerzone to grab their player ID and check to see what team they are on. If it's not greater than 0 move them onto a team with a `Set Team` chip.

Comment: I've suggested an edit, they just have to accept.